# How to Overwrite Dataframe NaN with Scraped Data

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a `df`:

```
  Company Name  Symbol      CUSIP
0       Aa Inc     NaN   26874784
4       Cc Inc     NaN  16117M305
7       Bb Inc     NaN  30734W208
```

and am looking up `Symbols` from the `CUSIP` via beautifulsoup. But when I scrape the `Symbols` and try writing to the `df`, the rows are still `NaN`, rather than containing the scraped `Symbol`, like so:

```
  Company Name      Symbol      CUSIP
0       Aa Inc         AIG   26874784
4       Cc Inc   No Symbol  16117M305
7       Bb Inc      FPAC/U  30734W208
```

How do I replace the `NaN` `Symbol` with the scraped `Symbol`?

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import time

# Crawl Fidelity.com to find symbols for new CUSIPs
base_url = "https://quotes.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml" \
           "?reqforlookup=REQUESTFORLOOKUP&productid=mmnet&isLoggedIn" \
           "=mmnet&rows=50&for=stock&by=cusip&criteria={}&submit=Search"

def read_symbol(cusip):
    r = requests.get(base_url.format(cusip))
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    symbol = soup.select_one('[href*=SID_VALUE_ID]')
    return symbol.text if symbol is not None else None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cusip = row['CUSIP']
    company_name = row['Company Name']
    for zeroes in range(3):
        symbol = read_symbol(zeroes * "0" + cusip)
        row['Symbol'] = 'No Symbol' if symbol is None else symbol
        if symbol is not None:
            break
    print(str(symbol) + " is the symbol for " + str(company_name) + " (CUSIP #: " + str(cusip) + ")")
    time.sleep(3)

print(df)
```

Comment: your question isn't clear ! I've moved to your mentioned url but it's not giving the output which you presented

Comment: i think  you can do: `df['Symbol'] = df['CUSIP'].str.zfill(9).map(read_symbol)` which returns `['AIG', nan, 'FPAC/U']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUSIP column must be read as a string column explicitly. So as to retain leading zeros. Also, you could use [pandas.Series.str.zfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) to pad zeros as `CUSIP` number is always 9 digit.

```
df['CUSIP'] = df['CUSIP'].astype(str).str.zfill(9)
```

Remove lxml parser from BeatifulSoup constructor

```
def read_symbol(cusip):
    r = requests.get(base_url.format(cusip))
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
    symbol = soup.select_one('[href*=SID_VALUE_ID]')
    return symbol.text if symbol is not None else np.nan
```

Use map and fillna

```
df['Symbol'] = df['CUSIP'].map(read_symbol).fillna('No Symbol')
```

Output

```
  Company Name     Symbol      CUSIP
0      Aa  Inc        AIG  026874784
4      Cc  Inc  No Symbol  16117M305
7      Bb  Inc     FPAC/U  30734W208
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael for helping out.

Comment: Thanks. I still probably need to `sleep` the function so as not to overload the url I am scraping, so should I stick it before the `return` statement? Also, when I remove lxml parser, I get a warning `UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified....To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.` I know I can ignore this without issue, but is there harm in keeping the lxml parser in order to suppress the warning?

Comment: Updated answer @MSD and yes you can sleep before return.